# What would be the SwiftUI (iOS native) equivalent implementation of an aria-live region announcing a "reminder" on web (ARIA)?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a web app that announces a "reminder" to screen readers every minute. I implement it with standard WAI-ARIA live regions:

```
<div id="reminder" aria-live="polite"></div>
```

```
setInterval(function() {
  
  var targetDiv = document.getElementById("reminder");
  targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p>This reminder is announced.</p>";

}, 60000);
```

**If ARIA is web only,** how is a similar implementation/outcome achieved if I were to implement this in a native iOS app using SwiftUI?

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you are looking for [`UIAccessibility.post`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post) to announce anything you want at any point in time:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    static let timer = Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var reminder: String = "This reminder is announced."
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(reminder)
                .onReceive(MyView.timer) { _ in
                    UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: reminder)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But really depends on your use case. If you don't want to repeat the same announcement for example, but only want to read out when it changes, you can use [`.accessibilityAddTraits(.updatesFrequently)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620187-updatesfrequently) modifier (good example [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/voiceover-for-frequently-updating-data/)):

```
...
Text(reminder)
    .onReceive(MyView.timer) { _ in
        reminder = "Read this value now"
    }
    .accessibilityAddTraits(.updatesFrequently)
...
```

Comment: Is there any resource that maps ARIA roles and attributes to UIaccessibility? Or something else that can help me transition from web to swiftUI in terms of a11y apis?

Comment: I haven't heard of any. But Apple does a good job providing a11y to the elements automatically, so most of the time you can just rely on default behavior. I.e. in example above `Text` will be read out properly without me providing any other clues to the system. Only in few cases - such as changing content, grouping of the elements (to read them out as one), or changing the nature of the element (e.g. reading out image as button) you need some manual adjustments. So my recommendation would be: develop SwiftUI (without any custom code), then test, and adjust only things that require adjustments.